# Is there a connected planar 3-regular graph on 2n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

As the title suggests I'm looking for connected planar 3-regular graphs on 2n vertices. If you drop the connected condition then this is easy. You can take disjoint unions of a prism and $K_{4}$. Is there an easy extension to connected graphs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following construction generalizes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An $n$-gonal prism (a prism where the two "ends" are not triangles but $n$-sided polygons) is a connected, planar, 3-regular graph on $2n$ vertices. It's not isomorphic to Greg Martin's family of examples, since (for $n>3$) the prism has no 3-cycles.

I can't draw pretty pictures, but it's a cycle $A_1,\dots,A_n$ inside a cycle $B_1,\dots,B_n$, with edges joining $A_i$ and $B_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

By the way, given any planar $k$-regular graph on $m$ vertices, it's easy to construct a connected planar $k$-regular graph on $m$ vertices. Let $uv$ be an "outside" edge on one component, $xy$ an outside edge on another component, erase those two edges, and add edges $ux$ and $vy$, reducing the number of components by one. Iterate until connectedness is achieved.